# Deploy minimal service to ECS Fargate without load balancer accessible via public internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, aws-fargate, service-discovery

I have a small application that I want to deploy to AWS with least cost as possible that would still allow the application to be accessible in the public internet and to grow further when required. In addition to that I wanted to streamline my pipeline and automate everything.

That's why I've chosen the following setup:

- AWS ECS
- AWS Fargate Spot
- AWS ServiceDiscovery
- no load balancer

I wanted to go without load balancer for now because it's simply too costly to start with, especially when I want to scale down the application completely from time to time.

What have so far:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: ECS deployment

Parameters:
  Image:
    Type: String
  Application:
    Type: String
  Namespace:
    Type: String
  Cluster:
    Type: String
  Cpu:
    Type: String
  Memory:
    Type: String

Resources:
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: !Ref Application
      ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::**:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      Cpu: !Ref Cpu
      Memory: !Ref Memory
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref Application
          Image: !Ref Image
          Cpu: !Ref Cpu
          Memory: !Ref Memory
          PortMappings:
            - HostPort: 8080
              ContainerPort: 8080
          Essential: true

  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: -1

  ServiceDiscoveryService:
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref Application
      DnsConfig:
        DnsRecords:
          - Type: A
            TTL: 300
        NamespaceId: !Ref Namespace
      HealthCheckCustomConfig:
        FailureThreshold: 1

  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      ServiceName: !Ref Application
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
      CapacityProviderStrategy:
        - Base: 0
          CapacityProvider: FARGATE_SPOT
          Weight: 1
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt SecurityGroup.GroupId
          Subnets:
            - **
            - **
            - **
      ServiceRegistries:
        - RegistryArn: !GetAtt ServiceDiscoveryService.Arn
```

I am not sure if I am at all able to run a container on Fargate with a different port than 80 if I am not using a load balancer. Because I read that SRV records can't be interpreted by curl and httpie. And I would definitely want to be able to call my api with that. And as I don't have a load balancer I can't configure a dynamic host mapping because that's not possible with Fargate.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html

> If you are using the Fargate launch type, the awsvpc network mode is required.
> With the host and awsvpc network modes, exposed container ports are mapped directly to the corresponding host port (for the host network mode) or the attached elastic network interface port (for the awsvpc network mode), so you cannot take advantage of dynamic host port mappings.

With the deployment above I was able to deploy everything to AWS and the task is running successfully. It has a public ip and I am able to query it from my laptop successfully with

```
http PUBLIC_IP/stocks/MMM
```

I have now registered a new domain, let's say `test-1234.com` and registered the name servers of my created hostzones.

Using `dig` for `my-service.test-1234.com` results in the private ip of the running task.
I would assume that's the expected answer for a successfully registered task but I am not sure.

Querying it with

```
http my-service.test-1234.com/stocks/MMM
```

is failing with  `Failed to establish a new connection`

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: You can assign an IP but can't use a domain as far as I know. see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=931880 -- Maybe you would need some workaround to attach the IP of the task to the DNS record, it can cause some issues.

Comment: You can't do that with fargate.

Comment: @juanfontes Do you think switching to EC2 Spot Instances instead of fargate could work together with a different NetworkMode?

Comment: I may be missing something but .... why using Service Discovery for this? Wouldn't you just want to spin up a Fargate task with a public IP and map it to the DNS of your hosted zone with a simple A Record? Of course you'd need to keep changing that mapping every time you provision a new task (with SPOT is more likely to occur). Also, have you considered [App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/) for this? Biggest thing is that it doesn't yet have SPOT support but...

Comment: @mreferre The service discovery part was the idea to automate the ip update of the tasks as every task can restart at any point in time. Even though I am running the setup with only one instance, I don't want to need to fix anything manually. Having to update the IP manually is not an option for me. Whereas I would accept some spontaneous downtime for the time being when it's only 1min or so.

I haven't considered App runner, but I will take a look. 
I will try the ECS on EC2 Spot instances as well. Let's see if one of these would work for me.

Comment: Oh I see what you were trying to do there. I *believe* that hosted zone is peculiar enough to not allow you to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @mreferre I checked the pricing for App Runner and it seems to be much more costly compared to ECS with the smallest EC2 instance type.

Pricing is dependent on resources consumed, at the rate of $0.064 per hour per vCPU and $0.007 per GB. A minimal instance (1vCPU, 2GB) will therefore cost $0.078 per hour or around $56.00 per month, plus a little extra for automatic build and deployment.

Whereas for ECS + EC2 Spot instances I would only pay for the EC2 instances. In my case even t2.small would be enough and would be $0.008 per hour which would mean not even 6$ per month.

Comment: The nice thing about App Runner is that it scales down to (almost) 0 when you are not hitting the endpoint. So it really depends on your workload patterns. There are examples at the bottom of the [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/pricing/) page. If you are actively hitting the app 24x7 then yes the cost is higher than if you are hitting it occasionally.

Comment: Ah i see, I missed the part in the pricing model with only paying for "active" instances. Thanks for the hint on the cost example. That is definitely an option then!

Comment: @mreferre Thank you again for mentioning App Runner. I have now everything successfully deployed. The only thing that's currently not yet working is to create the App Runner service via CloudFormation. Currently it's only possible via UI or CLI, but I hope that changes in the future.

Comment: Very cool. Happy you got it working and you are happy with the pricing. BTW CloudFormation is indeed supported. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apprunner-service.html). Or are you looking for something specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To summarize the comments:**

It's currently **not possible** to do that with Fargate.
More details [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=931880).

Nevertheless there are two other options that could work:

1. Deploy the containers on EC2 instead of Fargate, because there you use different Network Modes than only `awsvpc` and can configure the port mapping.
2. Deploy container via [AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/) where you can as well pause the services when you don't need them so that it's a low budget option as well and you don't need to take care of anything except for creating the App Runner service. The downside is that the creation of the App Runner service is currently only possible via CLI or UI but not yet via CloudFormation.